# Spark generator current limiter

Tags: generator, current-limiting, discharge, transducer

I am using a spark generator for electrical discharge machining and mounted a current transducer to read the current value of the arc between workpiece and electrode.

When the electrode gets too near to the workpiece, the current rises above 20 amperes.

I would like to limit the current to 20A.

Using resistors is not ideal so I am seeking advice.

Would it be possible to turn off the source until current is below limit and then turn it back on?

This would likely cause ripple.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Andyaka , avoid a short circuit by limiting the current to 20A

Comment: Avoid a short circuit by monitoring the current and moving the tool away from the workpiece when the current is too high.  You have to move the tool or the workpiece when doing EDM, so use the machine to move things to regulate the current.

Comment: The answer is yes. Is ripple a problem? Or you could use a current source.

Answer (score 0):

Electric discharge machining uses an automated mechanism to move the tool into the workpiece.

Monitor the current, then have the mechanism back the tool away from the workpiece when the current is too high.

In addition, you'll probably want some kind of automatic shutoff (a fuse or something) to kill power if the mechanism goes wonky.

1. Control the tool to control the current.
2. Emergency fallback to catch failures.